# PaperClip Error: has contents that are not what they are reported to be

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am trying to upload a pdf file using paper clip.

Here is my code:

**brochure.rb**

```
has_attached_file :brochure_pdf
  validates_attachment :brochure_pdf, content_type: { content_type: ['application/pdf'] }
```

**GemFile**

```
gem "paperclip", "~> 5.0.0"
```

While trying upload a file It shows the error **"Brochure pdf has contents that are not what they are reported to be"**

**Console Log:**

```
Command :: file -b --mime '/var/folders/8q/fw039jls5qnbgf3wyn955k5800015p/T/2b1e2bdd3860ad1b36820955b26fb78120180217-29896-1hmt413.pdf'
[paperclip] Content Type Spoof: Filename Designation_Tree-Ver_1.pdf (application/pdf from Headers, ["application/pdf"] from Extension), content type discovered from file command: . See documentation to allow this combination.
```

It gives the same error while uploading an image too. Please advise me what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
validates_attachment_content_type :brochure_pdf, content_type: ["application/pdf"],:message => 'Only pdf files are allowed'
```

Comment: Did you find the answer? If yes then post it.